# Block API calls from app to stop DDoS attacks

Tags: mobile, ddos, api

Recently we had a discussion about the security of a mobile app we are working on. The security team requested that if a user is blocked (due to many failed login attempts), then the back-end should return the date/time the block will be lifted, so that the mobile app will internally block all outgoing API calls until that date/time.

The reason quoted is that a user or a large number of users could attempt to do a 'fake login' to perform some sort of DDoS attack, and a way to stop that attack would be to make the app block these attempts if the user is blocked.

Does this make any sense? I can't find any arguments with or against this logic. but i personally don't see the benefit because a DDoS attack requires a very large number of requests per second.

Comment: wrt, `'so that the mobile app will internally block all outgoing API calls until that date/time'` - if an attacker is going to try to DDOS your API endpoint, they are not going to use your app to do it.  They are going to use a rented botnet, or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

When securing a back end, it is useless to do any assumption on the origin of the requests. Said differently, you **must** be prepared to received forged requests that the frond end could not send.

That means that asking the app to stop sending request is definitely not a way to secure the back end.

On the other hand, having the app being aware that it is blocked for failed login attempts could be used to display a user message explaining the reason why they cannot use the app, and when they could expect to be able to use it again. So it could certainly provide a better user experience. But it is unrelated to security.